# Помогите разобраться с моделью многие-ко-многим

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

Помогите разобраться. Возможно ли подключиться таблице `Timetable` к таблице `Group`, через табл. многие-ко многим `GroupTT`, через `Include`. Хочу вывести в таблице `Timetable` группу (Group/group_name) + фильтр по группам. До этого была БД со сложной моделью и все передавалось через `Include`. А как сейчас вывести все в одной таблице не знаю.

— CONTROLLER—

```
public async Task<actionresult> Index(int? group)
{
    IQueryable<timetable> timetables = db.Timetables.Include(p => p.NumLess.Dayw.NumWeek).Include(p => p.Room.Building).Include(r => r.Room.RoomType).Include(r => r.TypeLe)
.Include(r => r.GroupTTs);
    IQueryable<group> groups = db.Groups.Include(g => g.group_name).Include(g => g.group_id);
    if (group != null && group != 0)
    {
        timetables = timetables.Where(p => p.group_id == group);
    }

    List<group> groups = db.Groups.ToList();
    // устанавливаем начальный элемент, который позволит выбрать всех
    groups.Insert(0, new Group { group_name = "Все", group_id = 0 });

    //groups.Insert(0, new Group { group_name = "Все", group_id = 0 });
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    GroupsListViewModel glvm = new GroupsListViewModel
    {
        // Timetables = timetables.ToList(),
        Timetables = timetables.ToList(),
        ////////// Groups = new SelectList(groups, "group_id", "group_name"),

    };

    return View(glvm);
```

--Index Timetable--

```
@model TU1.Models.GroupsListViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>     
        <td><p>День</p></td>
        <td><p>распис_ид</p></td>
        <td><p>Время</p></td>
        <td><p>Корпус</p></td>
        <td><p>Ауд</p></td>
        <td><p>Тип</p></td>     
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model.Timetables)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NumLess.Dayw.dayw_shortname)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.timetable_id)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NumLess.numless_startime)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Room.Building.building_id)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Room.room_num)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TypeLe.typeles_name)
            </td>
            <td>                        
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.timetable_id }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.timetable_id }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.timetable_id })                      
            </td>
        </tr>     
    }    
</table>
```

--GroupsListViewModel--

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using TU1;


namespace TU1.Models
{
    public class GroupsListViewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<AcademPlan> AcademPlans { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Timetable> Timetables { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Lecturer> Lecturers { get; set; }
        public SelectList Groups { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Group> Group { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Хоть вначале и написано, что нужно через include, но как вариант вообще отказаться от include и получить данные через такой запрос (вообще можно без связей в таблицах)

```
        //Метод Join принимает четыре параметра:
        //вторую таблицу, которая соединяется с текущей
        //    свойство объекта - столбец из первой таблицы, по которому идет соединение
        //    свойство объекта -столбец из второй таблицы, по которому идет соединение
        //новый объект, который получается в результате соединения
        IQueryable<timetable> timetables = (
        from tb in db.Timetables
        join group in db.Groups on tb.group_ide equals group.Id
        ...
        join {сколько таблиц нужно объединить}
        where {добавили условие}
        select new GroupsListViewModel 
        {
           // Timetables = timetables.ToList(),
              Timetables = timetables.ToList(),
           ////////// Groups = new SelectList(groups, "group_id", "group_name"),
        });
return View(timetables);
```